# Перевод строки в математическое выражение Java

Tags: java

Как можно преобразовать строку, содержащую математическое выражение, чтобы можно было получить результат его решения?

Comment: занятно, закрыт как дубликат со ссылкой на дубликат =)

Answer (score -2):

Можете воспользоваться встроенным движком Javascript.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "(20+7)/3-7*10";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(expression));
}
```

В частности, дубликат англоязычного [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

Comment: а безопасно ли вызывать `eval`?

Comment: @trollingchar, в контексте конкретного кода да, а вот если код будет сменным и с отправкой на обработчик `eval`, то нет. Но все-же я бы не советовал использовать данный код, так как для этого есть `executor'ы`. Подобно драйверу `JavascriptExecutor` например. А вообще, вопрос не про `js`., а про Java и перевод из строки.

Comment: Раз вы уже смотрели дубликат вопроса и видели самый мажорный ответ, нужно было добавить оттуда также и комментарии - "It seems there's a major problem there; It executes a script, not evaluates an expression. To be clear, engine.eval("8;40+2"), outputs 42 ! If you want an expression parser that also check the syntax, I've just finished one (because I found nothing that suits my needs)"

Comment: и в частности "Security note: You should never use this in a server context with user input. The executed JavaScript can access all Java classes and thus hijack your application without limit."

Comment: и с того же дубликата лучшим решением здесь, имхо будет это https://stackoverflow.com/a/36366836/6908818 
топикстартер же не указал в условии - нужно ли ему делать это built-in средствами

Comment: Автор не уточнял условия задачи, какая секьюрность нужна и какие проблемы код должен решать, поэтому я скинул то, чего ему будет достаточно.